# My Iscroll wrapper doesn't get a height value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got the following code:

```
    <div data-role="content" height="100%" data-iscroll>
        <div class="homebutton_zeile">
            <a id="picture_home" href="#pictrues">
            <div class="homebutton_all">
                <div class="homebutton_name">Picture</div>
                    <div class="homebutton_picture">
                        <img src="images/picture.png" alt="image"
                                        style="position: relative;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My classes of CSS

```
.homebutton_zeile {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
}

.homebutton_all {
    width: 30%;
    height: 90%;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top:15px;
}

.homebutton_picture {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #AAC7BD;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow:8px 8px 8px #666;
}

.homebutton_name {
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    top:-10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
```

I am using:

- iscroll.js
- jQuery 1.8.2
- jQuery mobile 1.2.0
- jQuery mobile iscrollview.

And if its needed to know `jstorage.js` and `fastclick.js`

But the div above is not getting a height at the wrapper of iscroll. There is also a login before and this page will be shown automatically after the login after a `$.mobile.changePage("#home");` function.

I tried to do it as first page before the function of changePage and it gave me the same effect. If i put a   for example after the
`<div data-role="content" height="100%" data-iscroll>&nbps;`
The Wrapper get a height of 15px for the &nbps; but not for the images inside.

Comment: This is way beyond the whiteboard; you are in Stack Overflow terrain here.

Comment: Ok, what sort of questions do i ask in here then?

Comment: See the [FAQ]; rule of thumb: standing at the whiteboard (planning, architecture, etc.) ask it here, already coding, ask it at SO.